# ¿Cómo guardar valores en localStorage y restaurarlos al recargar la página?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero mantener los valores de los inputs que no se borren al recargar la página. Pero no se cómo aplicar el localStorage en mi código . La idea es que diariamente el usuario pueda agregar los valores y que se mantengan almacenados para llevar un control de cargas y depósitos.

```js
function sumar() {
    var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sabado").value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lunes").value);
    var re = b + c;
    document.getElementById("saldoC").innerHTML = (re);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="sabado" value="0" 
type="number" onclick= "limpiar2()">
   
    <input id= "lunes" value= "0" type= 
"number" onclick= "limpiar3()">

    <button id= "cal" 
onclick="sumar()">calcular</button>   
 
    <h2 id= "saldoC" >TOTAL</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente me fue de mucha utilidad, muchas gracias bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para guardar los valores en el localstorage, tendrías que usar `setItem()`, así:

```
function sumar() {
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sabado").value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lunes").value);
  var re = b + c;
  document.getElementById("saldoC").innerHTML = (re);
  
  localStorage.setItem("sabado", b); // guardo el valor de b en el localstorage.
  localStorage.setItem("lunes", c); // guardo el valor de c en el localstorage.
}
```

Y para recoger los valores del localstorage y ponerlo en el input, sería algo así:

```
// al momento de recargar la página...
window.onload = function() {
  // obtengo el valor del localstorage y lo asigno al valor de los inputs.
  document.getElementById("sabado").value = localStorage.getItem("sabado") || "0";
  document.getElementById("lunes").value = localStorage.getItem("lunes") || "0";
}
```

Aquí utilizo el operador `||` para establecer un valor predeterminado en caso de que el valor obtenido desde el localStorage sea `null` o `undefined`.

---

Referencias:

- **`setItem()`**: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem
- **`getItem()`**: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem